# Can you call functions from an imported module without calling the module in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, module, node-modules

Kind of a dumb question, just wanted to try out if you could just avoid the name of the required module.

For example:

```
const MATH = require('./maths.js');
HTTP.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.write("Add 1 and 5: " + MATH.add(1, 5));
}).listen(8080);

// Add in the maths module
// function add(a, b) {
//     return a + b;
// }
```

Would I be able to somewhat do the following?

response.write("Add 1 and 5: " + add(1,5));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can by using ES6 destructuring. How? Like this:

```
const { add } = require('./maths.js');

HTTP.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.write("Add 1 and 5: " + add(1, 5));
}).listen(8080);

// Add in the maths module
// function add(a, b) {
//     return a + b;
// }
```

Should work in Node 10+ (even earlier)

Comment: This worked perfectly! 
Is there a way to make it work when the export module is an object?

Comment: Destructuring is a generic language feature. So it can be anything that get's exported.